# How to display my filter data combination of selected dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, filter

How to display data only where it is matching values of combined dropdowns?

Right now if I am selecting value **Thulasiram.S from dropdown A, Value 11 from dropdown B**. If in my data if I have value **Thulasiram.S** and **Value 11** it is showing all the results matching.

Thulasiram.S    11  Chess   1   Day

ST Ram  11  Cricket 1   Month

So, output should only show

Thulasiram.S    11  Chess   1   Day

because I have selected value Thulasiram.S from dropdown A, Value 11 from dropdown B.

Please suggest.

```js
$('#test213').click(function () {
    getSelectedVal()
});


function getSelectedVal() {
    var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text()
    var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text()
    var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text()
    var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text()

    filterData(startDate)
    filterData(duetDate)
    filterData(templateName)
    filterData(status)
}


function filterData(data) {
    if (data != '') {
        var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();
        rows.filter(":contains('" + data + "')").show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="option1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Thulasiram.S</option>
    <option>ST Ram</option>
    <option>Ram Kumar.S</option>
    <option>Dinesh Kumar.S  </option>
</select>

<select id="option2">
    <option></option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="option3">
    <option></option>
    <option>Chess</option>
    <option>Cricket</option>
</select>
<select id="option4">
    <option></option>
    <option>Day</option>
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>Week</option>
</select>
<button id="test213">Add filter</button>
<table id="ticketList">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="shelulerData">
        <tr>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sport</th>
            <th>Class </th>
            <th>Term</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Day">
            <td>Thulasiram.S</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Day</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Month">
            <td>ST Ram</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Cricket</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Month</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="21" data-class="2" data-term="Day">
            <td>Ram Kumar.S</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Day</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="30" data-class="3" data-term="Week">
            <td>Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Week</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> filterData(startDate)
> filterData(duetDate)
> filterData(templateName)
> filterData(status)
> ```

You're basically performing an **OR**-based filter yet what you need is an **AND**-based filter.

Instead of calling `filterData(...)` multiple times, call it once and concatenate the filters inside that method.

```js
function getSelectedVal() {
    var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text();
    var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text();
    var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text();
    var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text();

    filterData([startDate, duetDate, templateName, status]);
}


function filterData(data) {
    const filters = data.filter(f => f.trim() !== "");

    if (filters.length !== 0) {
        var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();
        const selectors = filters.map(f => `tr:contains('${f}')`).join('');

        rows.filter(selectors).show();
    }
}
```

##### Addendum

The above solution will perform a case-sensitive **AND**-based filter.
If you need a case-insensitive search, convert the `tr` tag text to upper/lower case and compare it against your filters. I.e:

```js
function getSelectedVal() {
    var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text();
    var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text();
    var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text();
    var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text();

    filterData([startDate, duetDate, templateName, status]);
}

function filterData(data) {
    const filters = data.filter(f => f.trim() !== "");

    if (filters.length !== 0) {
        var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();

        rows.each(function () {
            if (filters.every(f => $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(('' + f).toUpperCase()) !== -1)) $(this).show();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @KunalVijan Does this answer your *reset filter* question? [Filter data](https://codepen.io/theAccountant/pen/abVRzNy)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create composite filters. The problem is that your second filter overrides the first one instead of adjusting it.

```js
$('#test213').click(function () {
    getSelectedVal()
});


function getSelectedVal() {
    var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text();
    var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text();
    var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text();
    var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text();

    filterData([startDate, duetDate, templateName, null, status]);
}


function filterData(data) {
    if (data != '') {
        var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();
        for (let row of rows) {
            let shouldShow = true;
            for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                if (data[index]) shouldShow = shouldShow && (row.children[index].innerText === data[index]);
                //console.log([should])
            }
            if (shouldShow) $(row).show();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="option1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Thulasiram.S</option>
    <option>ST Ram</option>
    <option>Ram Kumar.S</option>
    <option>Dinesh Kumar.S  </option>
</select>

<select id="option2">
    <option></option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="option3">
    <option></option>
    <option>Chess</option>
    <option>Cricket</option>
</select>
<select id="option4">
    <option></option>
    <option>Day</option>
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>Week</option>
</select>
<button id="test213">Add filter</button>
<table id="ticketList">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="shelulerData">
        <tr>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sport</th>
            <th>Class </th>
            <th>Term</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Day">
            <td>Thulasiram.S</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Day</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Month">
            <td>ST Ram</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Cricket</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Month</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="21" data-class="2" data-term="Day">
            <td>Ram Kumar.S</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Day</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="30" data-class="3" data-term="Week">
            <td>Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Week</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you suggest a better way to hide all the data instead of showing everything upfront? maybe create a API and get data from that or any sugestions?

Comment: @KunalVijan yes, of course. You can create an API and in fact you should. However, it is outside the boundaries of this question. If you do not want to show anything upfront, but you don't mind that all the rows are present (but hidden), then you could hide everything at the initial stage. If this is unhelpful, then I guess I need more information about your expectations. If this answer solved your issue, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.